# Set currency .00 in staging SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, currency, data-warehouse, staging

I work with SSIS (SQL Server Integration System) and data related to currency. I want to normalize the currency so that every value followed by .00. For example, the 85000 to be 85000.00. But, if the value already followed by .00, no need to add the .00.

Can anybody help me to deal with it?

Comment: Surely if you store your numbers if the correct numerical datatype you can leave display of decimal points to the front end?

Comment: The number of trailing decimal zeros *doesn't* matter. This won't affect calculations and if you really need data to appear a certain way, you need to format it when displaying. If you insist though, simply multiply by `1.00`. No need to play with strings.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use a data flow task, so take these steps:

1. Add Derived Column component.
2. Add this code `(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)(FINDSTRING([value],".",1) != 0 ? [value]: [value]+ ".00")`

Good luck